# Distribution of distances to a hyperplane

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, euclidean-geometry, geometric-probability

Suppose I have the unit sphere in $R^3$ and WLOG have a hyperplane be the $x-z$ plane. I uniformly at random choose points within the sphere. I know that the distribution of the coordinates of those points is uniform, but what is the distribution of the distances to the hyperplane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we randomly choose a point $P(X,Y,Z)$ inside the unit ball with uniform distribution:
$$
f(x,y,z) = \frac{3}{4\pi},\,x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1
$$
Then, as you say, WLOG we would like to find the distribution of the distance between $P$ and the plane $y=0$. That is $|Y|$, we now find the c.d.f. of this random variable.
$$
F_Y(y) =P(|Y|\leq y)= \frac{3}{4\pi}\int_{-y}^y\pi(1-y^2)\,dy=\frac{3}{2}[y-\frac{1}{3}y^3]\quad(0<y<1)
$$
And the p.d.f. is
$$
f_Y(y)= \frac{3}{2}(1-y^2)\quad(0<y<1)
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you expand a little more on the derivative of the CDF (particularly the body of the integral?)

Comment: typo: derivation* not derivative

Comment: @a6623 $P(|Y|\leq y)=\frac{3}{4\pi}\iiint_{V}\,dx\,dy\,dz$, where $V=\{(X,Y,Z)|x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1,-y \leq Y \leq y\}$, then the integral becomes $\frac{3}{4\pi}\int _{-y}^(y)\,dy \iint_{x^2+z^2\leq 1-y^2}\,dx\,dz$